# WordPress Filter: Replace full content before page renders

Tags: wordpress, filter, action, hook

I'm trying to mesh Mustache Templating Engine with WordPress. So far, I have been very successful using the_content as a filter to parse my template tags e.g. {{ something }}.

However, if let’s say, a developer hardcodes the template tags directly into the page template e.g. loop-page, the_content doesn’t capture the hardcoded tags.

Is there a filter that will allow me to capture the content of the whole page template including the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing a plugin, you can use PHP function [ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php) to cache whole buffered content. After that you can use callback function to return replaced content.

Use triggers (action's) [init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) or after_setup_theme for your script.

Comment: thank you! you are right. I hooked up ob_start to wp_head and ob_end_flush to wp_footer and it worked like a charm.